# window operating system vulnerability scanner tool

Tags: windows-server

I want to use window operating system vulnerability scanner tool, just like lynis tools which scans on local os i.e like misconfiguration, os version, like firewall and AV configured. please recommend me the tools which do this kind of scan?

Comment: Sorry, software recommendations are off-topic for this site (see the [tour](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour) page).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Windows 10, the [Windows Defender Security Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-security-center/windows-defender-security-center) will track for the presence and configuration of antivirus, firewall, account protection, app/browser controls, and device security.